# What are the difference between the thread dumps

Tags: java, thread-safety, thread-dump

What are the difference between the thread dumps taken by ctrl+break and java program?
I am using the below snippet to get thread dump

Map  st = Thread.getAllStackTraces();

Answer (score 2):

`Thread.getAllStackTraces` does not include information about thread statuses or locks they hold or locks they waiting for. You'll need to get this info from elsewhere (there's `ThreadMXBean` for this).

Comment: Thanks, i want to get the thread dump from a java program which should have all the information what are all present while taking thread dump on ctrl+break. How can i?

Comment: Consult JDK documentation for `ThreadMXBean` and `ThreadInfo`